# Computation of Coriolis Matrix

Tags: control, dynamics

I am controlling a 6-DOF robot. For this, I want to compute the Coriolis Matrix. From my study of examples, I understand there are several ways of going about it. At the moment, I am using the theory based on, "A Lie group formulation of Robot dynamics" [p. 615] by Park et al. But this is not computationally efficient as my simulations are very slow.
Based on my study of several projects on Github, I understand many people choose symbolic approach. I was also considering numerical differentiation to get the Christoffel symbols.

I would like seek some guidance regarding the pros and cons of the different methods. I would really appreciate any references that I can use to study.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, MishraHrishik. As it stands, this is kind of a vague and open-ended question. It appears that you're assuming your slow simulations are due to your calculation of the Coriolis matrix. What simulation software are you using? Matlab/Simulink? Are you using any toolboxes or a homebrew simulator? Have you timed all the sections of your code? Can you post the code you're using to run the simulation? Is there a reason you cannot use a symbolic approach?

Comment: If you would like "pros and cons of different methods," please identify the methods you're interested in and what it is you are not sure of about those methods. I know this is a challenging topic, but you need to explain more about what you know, what you've done, and what's giving you trouble. A detailed answer to "Please explain pros and cons of different methods of calculating a 6DOF Coriolis matrix" is [probably a textbook.](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/mlswiki/index.php/Robot_Dynamics_and_Control)

Comment: Also, please state clearly if you are interested only in the Coriolis Matrix or generally in modelling dynamics. The (Recursive) Newton-Euler rmethod is computationally more efficitent then Lagrange. For a detailed explanation you can check https://books.google.de/books/about/Robotics_Control_Sensing_Vis.html?id=_oYYRzSohJgC&redir_esc=y

Comment: For computational efficiency it's best to stay away from symbolic representations.

Comment: symbolic representation are generally useful if you intend to demonstrate properties of your system otherwise iterative methods are more suited from a computational efficiency point of view

Comment: Closing the question as OP appears to have abandoned it with no further clarification.